# getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) returns null

Tags: android, android-sensors

Im developing an app on android that has to use the Rotation vector sensor, 
The phone im using for testing is a Samsung Galaxy Express 2 and it has all the sensors needed for rotation vector but still this:

sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)

returns null?

Anyone who knows why?

Comment: do you register listener for this sensor?

Comment: No i need the getDefaultSensor to return not null first to register it , like this: sensorManager.registerListener(mEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

Comment: aha i assumed sensor values return null. probably your gyro not working. you can test your sensors via [secret codes] (http://mashable.com/2014/10/27/samsung-galaxy-hidden-menu/#8QU63Q5wluqy). if it doesnt work use some sensor test app from google play store and see if they are working. If you have a hardware problem with gyro. you can use Sensor.TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR for API 19+ which uses magnetometer instead of gyro. Or use acc and mag and use a sensor fusion algortihm.

Comment: Ok, i tested that secret menu and the sensors seem to work, i got Magnetic sensor and accelerometer sensor showing correct values but still no rotation vector :/

Comment: Isnt Magnetic Sensor gyro?

Comment: Not of course, magnetic sensors are compasses and gyroscope measures angular velocities(deg/sec). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope

Comment: but the magnetic sensors on my phone shows azimuth, pitch and roll, that doesnt sound like a compass?

Comment: it must be geomagnetic rotation vector which is software-based sensor. that means android uses compass and accelerometer to provide rotation  vector. This is useful when gyroscope is not available. For better understanding sensors you should read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-geomrot